# numpy logical operation on 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose we have a set of values: `n`-rows and `6` columns (n,6).
How to replace 4th element in a row to be equal to the 3rd element if the 3rd element is more than the 4th?

I tried to do it in such a way:.

```
griddata[:,3][griddata[:,2] > griddata[:,3]] = griddata[:,2]
```

> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead:

```
griddata[:,3] = np.where(griddata[:,2] > griddata[:,3], griddata[:,2], griddata[:,3])
```

That replaces `griddata[:,3]` with `griddata[:,2]` everywhere that the condition (`griddata[:,2] > griddata[:,3]`) is True otherwise with the third argument (the original): `griddata[:,3]`.

A small sample:

```
>>> griddata = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6], [6,5,4,3,2,1]])
>>> griddata
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]])

>>> griddata[:,3] = np.where([griddata[:,2] > griddata[:,3]], griddata[:,2], 
>>> griddata
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [6, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1]])
```

---

### Why your approach can't work:

`griddata[:,3][griddata[:,2] > griddata[:,3]]` contains `x` elements where `x` is the number of `True` for your condition, however `griddata[:,2]` contains always `n` elements. So in any case (except when `griddata[:,2] > griddata[:,3]` is True for all rows) you will try to put `n` items in `x` slots. That just can't work.

You would need to mask both sides to make it work:

```
griddata[:,3][griddata[:,2] > griddata[:,3]] = griddata[:,2][griddata[:,2] > griddata[:,3]]
#                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Elegant and simple. I didn't know, that where takes those additional arguments. Awesome.

Comment: I think that's actually the original purpose of `np.where`, it's just so useful that it ends up used for almost everything (including replacing `np.nonzero` in a lot of code).

Comment: Masking both sides is probably going to be faster, especially if only a few of the items need to be overwritten.